# initialize google api v3 calendarservice with predefined token

Tags: google-oauth

I have a server application that needs to read all calendar entries of user calendars. Users have already authorized and i've stored the authcode and refresh token in my server database.  Can i initialize a calendar api v3 calendarservice with the oauth2 token that i have saved? i can't figure out how to get it work without asking for user authorization at run time.

i have this working, but i can't determine how to inialize the service with a predefined token.

```
            Dim myscopes As String() = New String() {CalendarService.Scope.Calendar} ' New () {CalendarService.Scope.Calendar}
        Dim secrets As New ClientSecrets() With { _
             .ClientId = rs.OAuth2Parameters.ClientId, _
             .ClientSecret = rs.OAuth2Parameters.ClientSecret _
        }
        Dim credential As UserCredential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(secrets, myscopes, "sellggltest1@gmail.com", System.Threading.CancellationToken.None).Result

        Dim service = New CalendarService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With { _
             .HttpClientInitializer = credential, _
             .ApplicationName = rs.Application _
        })


        Dim request As CalendarListResource.ListRequest = service.CalendarList.List()
        Dim events As Data.CalendarList = request.Execute()
```